# Implementing Python in Html inside Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 10)).to_html()

  myPage = """
          <html>
            <body>
              <h2> Website </h2>
              <form action="/helloworld" method="get">
              <select id = "options">
                <option value="">""</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
              </form>
              <button type="button" onclick="showText()">Go!</button>
              <div id="show" style="display:none;"></div>
            <script>

            function showText(){
              var value = document.getElementById('options').value;
                document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "you chose " + value;
                document.getElementById('show').style.display = "block";
              }
            </script>
            </body>
          </html>"""
return HttpResponse(myPage)
```

This is my code right now. It runs on a local server using Django, and all it does is show a dropdown menu, and when I select an option a block shows up that says "you chose this option". What I want is that when I choose a dropdown option and hit the button, it will return the dataframe I created at the very start. I think this may have to be done using ajax and jquery, but I don't really know anything about that. I've been trying to read up on it but I have no idea how I would implement something that ties together my python and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Django operates server-side, so any computation you'd like to do with Django (or Python) must be done on the server. The server then passes messages (requests and responses) back and forth to the client (ie. a browser). If you want to return some sort of data to Django, you'll have to use a form to submit the information via POST (a request), or you'll need to use Ajax,JQuery. If Django receives a POST request from the client, it can access data at `request.POST['myinteger']` for example, and can perform some computation with that integer, then return another HTTPResponse.

Remember, Django is only able to see and interact with things present on the server. Once sent across the Internet, it has no control. That is where Ajax/JQuery, etc. kick in. They can manipulate data on the client side (the browser downloads JQuery when it loads the page). To send data back and forth, you need to rely on sending requests and responses. This is accurate even when using a RESTful API.

I hope this explanation helps a bit.